# Is there any way to make VLC play a loaded film automatically at a specific time?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Are there any apps or some way I can get VLC to play an already set-up film at a given time?  No scripts please; don't know how to use them.  I just want VLC to start playing on it's own without any human interaction.  Any "gadgets" out there?  There has to be some simple app out there to nudge VLC alive!

Basically, I want the app to be able to know which open VLC window (if there's many open) to go to to press play say, at midnight.

Win 7.
IE 9.

Comment: What do you mean by already loaded? In the play queue, so to say? And what do you expect other than a script of some sort? It's a scripted action...

Comment: Hi, I am not sure whether it is possible to set VLC to automatically start playing a movie after program start. If yes, then you probably could use Windows Task Scheduler http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task

Comment: @slhck:...as in a file is ready to play but I need something to press play.

Comment: @Juhele: No, not at program start but just a tool to press play at a specfic time.

Comment: What about AutoIt? http://www.autoitscript.com

Comment: Other, maybe simpler alternatives: http://www.spacetornado.com/DoItAgain/ or http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/WinMacro.shtml

Comment: @Juhele: So in the macro apps we can choose a time like 11:30pm and it will play an already setup film in a VLC?

Comment: It was just an idea. Do not have direct experience with it. Just try :-D But at least in some of them this should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said no scripts, but it really is the easiest way.

Open Notepad and paste this into the Notepad window:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "VLC Media Player"
WScript.sleep(200)
WshShell.SendKeys " "
```

Choose File -> Save As and save the file as `VLCPlay.vbs`.

Now whenever you run the script (which you can test by double clicking the file), it will make VLC player the active window and press play (or pause if it was already playing).

Now use windows [task scheduler](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html) to run the .vbs file at midnight and you're done.

PS. If you really hate scripts, [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vxxe8nlan2zxmr3/VLCPlay.vbs?dl=1) is a "gadget" that will do it, just use [task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) to start it at midnight.

Comment: Why would I double click the file?  I'm lost.

Comment: Double clicking it will run the script, but if you want to run it at a certain time, use windows' task scheduler.

Comment: What if there are multiple VLC windows open which one will run?